# Removing words from a file

Tags: python, string, list, file-io, python-3.x

I'm trying to take a regular text file and remove words identified in a separate file (stopwords) containing the words to be removed separated by carriage returns ("\n").

Right now I'm converting both files into lists so that the elements of each list can be compared. I got this function to work, but it doesn't remove all of the words I have specified in the stopwords file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
def elimstops(file_str): #takes as input a string for the stopwords file location
  stop_f = open(file_str, 'r')
  stopw = stop_f.read()
  stopw = stopw.split('\n')
  text_file = open('sample.txt') #Opens the file whose stop words will be eliminated
  prime = text_file.read()
  prime = prime.split(' ') #Splits the string into a list separated by a space
  tot_str = "" #total string
  i = 0
  while i < (len(stopw)):
    if stopw[i] in prime:
      prime.remove(stopw[i]) #removes the stopword from the text
    else:
      pass
    i += 1
  # Creates a new string from the compilation of list elements 
  # with the stop words removed
  for v in prime:
    tot_str = tot_str + str(v) + " " 
  return tot_str
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution using a generator expression.

```
tot_str = ' '.join(word for word in prime if word not in stopw)
```

To make this more efficient, turn `stopw` into a `set` using `stopw = set(stopw)`.

You might be having issues with your current approach if sample.txt is not just a space separated file, for example if you have normal sentences with punctuation then splitting on space will leave the punctuation as a part of a word.  To fix this you can use the `re` module to split your string on whitespace or punctuation:

```
import re
prime = re.split(r'\W+', text_file.read())
```

Comment: I don't think that's necessary -- he's iterating over `stopw` and removing elements from `prime`

Comment: @SamMussmann Thanks, I had just noticed that.  Edited my answer with the theory that punctuation is causing issues for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python, but here is a general way to do it which is O(n)+O(m) time - linear.

1: Add all words from stopwords file to a map.
2: Read your regular text file and try to add the words to a list.
While you do #2 check if currently read word is in map, if it is skip it, otherwise add it to list.

At the end, the list should have all the words that you need - the words that you wanted removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that this line:

```
    if stopw[i] in prime:
      prime.remove(stopw[i]) #removes the stopword from the text
```

Will only remove the first occurrence of `stopw[i]` from `prime`.  To fix this, you should do this:

```
    while stopw[i] in prime:
      prime.remove(stopw[i]) #removes the stopword from the text
```

However, this is going to run very slowly, because both the `in prime` and the `prime.remove` bits are going to have to iterate over prime.  This means that you'll end up with a [quadratic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) running time in the length of your string.  If you use a generator like F.J. [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13015996/600110), your running time will be linear, which is much better.